# How to convert xpath values in to JSON array

Tags: php, android, json, dom, xpath

I tried to get data from web sites using xpath and convert it into JSON array.

this is the result i got

{"mobiles":[{"model":3,"price":"Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500"},{"model":5,"price":"Rs. 109,900"},{"model":10,"price":"Samsung Galaxy Note N7000"},{"model":12,"price":"Rs. 63,000"},{"model":17,"price":"Dialog i43"},{"model":19,"price":"Rs. 16,490"},{"model":24,"price":"Micromax X1i XTRA"},{"model":26,"price":"Rs. 3,290"},{"model":31,"price":"Micromax X103"},{"model":33,"price":"Rs. 2,390"},{"model":38,"price":"Micromax A110 Canvas 2"},{"model":40,"price":"Rs. 25,990"}]}

i want to print this array like

{"mobiles":[{"model":Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500,"price":"109,900"},etc...

This the code i used

```
    @$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@class='span2 product_box']");

$models = array();
$models1 = array();

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {

            $modle = trim($node->nodeValue,"\t,\n,\r");
            $models[] = $modle;

        }
    }
}

$models1 = array_filter(array_map('trim', $models));

foreach($models1 as $key => $val)
{
    $result[] = array('model'=> $key, 'price'=> $val);  
}

$finalResultArray = array(
        'mobiles' => $result
);

echo json_encode($finalResultArray);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should maybe rethink the logic which fills your `$models` array.

Comment: when i echo $models it display like this   => Samsung Galaxy Note 3 3G N9000 Rs. 110,000 Samsung Star 3 Duos S5222 Rs. 14,999 Samsung Galaxy Express I8730 Rs. 41,000 Samsung Galaxy S4 mini DUOS I9192 Rs. 54,950 Samsung Galaxy S4 mini I9190 Rs. 56,000 Samsung Galaxy Core I8262 Rs. 34,500 Samsung Galaxy Core I8260 Rs. 34,900 Samsung Galaxy Mega 5.8 I9152 Rs. 64,900 Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3 I9200 Rs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = '{"mobiles":[{"model":3,"price":"Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500"},{"model":5,"price":"Rs. 109,900"},{"model":10,"price":"Samsung Galaxy Note N7000"},{"model":12,"price":"Rs. 63,000"},{"model":17,"price":"Dialog i43"},{"model":19,"price":"Rs. 16,490"},{"model":24,"price":"Micromax X1i XTRA"},{"model":26,"price":"Rs. 3,290"},{"model":31,"price":"Micromax X103"},{"model":33,"price":"Rs. 2,390"},{"model":38,"price":"Micromax A110 Canvas 2"},{"model":40,"price":"Rs. 25,990"}]}';
```

test it with:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($var,true));
echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [mobiles] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [model] => 3
                    [price] => Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [model] => 5
                    [price] => Rs. 109,900
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [model] => 10
                    [price] => Samsung Galaxy Note N7000
                )
)
```

Comment: you should get an array, so don't use echo. try $res = json_decode($finalResultArray, true); and then print_r($res);

Comment: Shao Khan i want to print it as like this.   {"mobiles":[{"model":"Samsung Galaxy S3 I9300","price":"Rs 58,000.00"},{"model":"Samsung Galaxy Core Duos I8262","price":"Rs 36,500.00"},{"model":"Samsung Galaxy Note 2 LTE N7105","price":"Rs 71,500.00"},{"model":"Samsung Galaxy S4 LTE I9505","price":"Rs 82,500.00"},{"model":"Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100","price":"Rs 42,000.00"} Then i want to send that JSON into android application.